# PHP Require is not working as I expected

Tags: php

Please review the below code and advise what is wrong with it when using require.

First here is the code that works (not using require in it):

```
<?php
//require("_start.inc");
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    echo "<h1 style='color:red'>Please <a href='../index.php'>login</a> first!</h1>";
}
else
{
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Main window</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Admin panel</h1>
<?php
require("header.inc");
?>
</body>

</html> 
<?php
//require("_end.inc");
}
?>
```

And here is the version that doesn't work, _start.inc and _end.inc are exactly what is written in the above code, but the below one give me an error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_start.inc on line 9

```
<?php
require("_start.inc");
/*session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    echo "<h1 style='color:red'>Please <a href='../index.php'>login</a> first!</h1>";
}
else
{
*/
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Main window</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Admin panel</h1>
<?php
require("header.inc");
?>
</body>

</html> 
<?php
require("_end.inc");
//}
?>
```

Comment: What is this file called - is the one you have presented "admin_start.inc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an opening brace in one and the corresponding closing brace in the other file.   Includes doesn't work like copy&paste. The files always must still be valid.

Btw: Use an IDE. It will tell you about such errors.

Comment: I see now that include/require doesn't work like copy/paste. But isn't there some language construct that work that way? If there isn't then i will have to plan my code better i suppose. Thanks for the answer.